# Inconsistent Object Speed on Canvas on Different devices.

Tags: android, canvas

Is it possible to make an object move at the same relative speed on a canvas on multiple devices with different screen sizes and densities?

At first I simply trued to have a speed variable:

```
public int speed = 40;
```

This produced inconsistent results on different devices.

```
public int speed = screenWidth / 40;
```

This still produced bad results so I tried doing this:

```
spd = (int) (Math.pow(MainActivity.deviceDensity, 2) + spd);
```

But the results are still inconsistent. So how do I make an Object move across a canvas at consistent speeds on different devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the second equation you have will give you a perfect result, as long you calculate the screen width and the calculated the time it would take to cross to other side.

So lets say you have a constant time it takes to reach on the other side:

`constant time = 4 seconds/4000 milliseconds;`

That would be the same to all devices, `speed = distance/time` that would be the equation to calculate the speed as long you have the `distance` the screen width and the `time` you will have the same speed on all devices.

**sample:**

```
distanceX = 1980;
constant time = 4 seconds/4000 milliseconds;
speed = 0.495;

distanceX = 1280;
constant time = 4 seconds/4000 milliseconds;
speed = 0.32;
```

as you can see the speed **decreases** as we use less `PPI` which is perfect.

Comment: So device density shouldn't matter when using this?

Comment: @TastyLemons nope they will have the same speed as long to have the constant time to arrival in the equation